# How do I align these DIV Elements to the top?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get these two DIV Elements (Image and Description fields) to the top of the box.  I can't seem to find the right CSS combination to pull this off.

The DIV order is:
search-gallery
search-result
gallery-img
search-info
title
series
genre
cast

[image: Webview]
[image: CSS]
[image: HTML]

Comment: `.search-result` now you have `align-items: center;`, but did you try `align-items: flex-start;`?

Comment: Perfect! I'll read up on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use align-items: flex-start to your .search-result. Also have look at this guide about flex-box: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Yep, that did it! I need to study a little more on how flex works. Thanks.